# Vimscript infinite loop

Tags: vimscript, plugin-ultisnips, plugin-fzf

I'm trying to combine [fzf-bibtex](https://github.com/msprev/fzf-bibtex) with [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips) so that I can search my bibliography file and insert a BibTeX key automatically. I use the following function from `fzf-bibtex` (which calls the binaries `bibtex-cite` and `bibtex-ls` on my system, they just format and output the BibTeX key):

```
function! s:bibtex_cite_sink_insert(lines)
    let r=system("bibtex-cite ", a:lines)
    execute ':normal! i' . r
    call feedkeys('a', 'n')
endfunction

inoremap <silent> @@ <c-g>u<c-o>:call fzf#run({
                        \ 'source': 'bibtex-ls',
                        \ 'sink*': function('<sid>bibtex_cite_sink_insert'),
                        \ 'up': '40%',
                        \ 'options': '--ansi --layout=reverse-list --multi --prompt "Cite> "'})<CR>
```

And in my `markdown.snippets` file I have the following snippet:

```
snippet q "Quote" i
[$1, $2] $0
endsnippet
```

If i now press `@@` in insert mode when at position `$1` after the snipped expanded, it works fine and the `fzf` prompt with my BibTeX entries is opened.

However, I wanted to automatically call this prompt when the snippet expanded. I thought that could maybe be done with telling vim to just type in `@@` when at snippet position `$1`, so I said:

```
snippet q "Quote" i
[`!v feedkeys('@@')`, $2] $0
endsnippet
```

The `fzf` prompt gets indeed invoked, but it stays in an *infinite* loop after it entered the selected key, opening the prompt again and again. I can't even quit it with `Esc` or `Ctrl-c`.

What did I do wrong? Thanks for helping.